# What is the pythonic way walk and manipulate an AST?

Tags: python-3.x, pattern-matching, abstract-syntax-tree

I am doing some code analysis, and have been let down by Python's so called 'Structural Pattern Matching.' I am trying to find function definitions (ast.FunctionDef) in an AST. I thought to do this by matching on the walk generator, which yields 'nodes'. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) does not specify much more. I am using Python 3.12.1.

```
def find_fn(tree) -> ast.FunctionDef:
   for node in ast.walk(tree):
      match node:
        case ast. FunctionDef (fd): return fd #always returns type 'str'
        case _: pass
   return None
```

I had to resort to this, which is much worse in my opinion:

```
def find_fn(tree) -> ast.FunctionDef:
   for node in ast.walk(tree) :
      if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef) :
         return node #returns ast.FunctionDef
    return None
```

Is there a feature of the pattern matching I am missing? My use case seems to be a trivial use case of pattern matching in an object oriented environment. Am I wrong in assuming there is some object oriented structure to the AST objects (It would make sense to me to have a parent Node class, with children such as FunctionDefNode).